# Dates not saving correctly in react-native realm

Tags: react-native, realm

I have an object with the following schema:

```
{
   name: "TestModel",
   properties: {
      "dateCreated": "date"
   }
}
```

Whenever I save the model to the database with dateCreated: new Date(), the date itself appears to be saved incorrectly.

I open the .realm file up in Realm Browser and it's listing a date in year 48212.  Does the react-native version of Realm store the dates in a different format than iOS and Java?  Is there a way I can force it to store the dates in the same format?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like date is stored differently across bindings - The JS code is storing milliseconds, while the browser/ios/swift bindings store seconds. I verified that by dividing the time by 1000 before storing the date resulted in the current time in the browser. I created an issue on github to track the issue: https://github.com/realm/realm-js/issues/355

There were already near term plans to migrate to a new date format that would be compatible across all the bindings, so if that is coming as soon as hoped we may wait until then to auto-migrate the JS date format.

Comment: Awesome, thanks for letting me know.  For now we are just storing our dates as ints and will wait for the cross-platform date format to be implemented.  Thanks again!

Comment: @Abhay - if you are only working in react-native the data stored will work fine but will only show up incorrectly in the browser or if trying to use the data across multiple bindings. Realm will be moving to a new date format in the next few weeks which will address this problem for the longer term. For now you can convert between the two types by getting the date to milli-seconds by calling `getTime()` and dividing by 1000 to convert to seconds.

Comment: @Ari - Thanks for the response... I figured that it is just storing the data differently, when i request the date from the Realm object... I get the correct date. So, I hope with the change in implementation it will not break my current data? - Not sure if you know about it.

Comment: @Abhay - when the changes is made there will be an automatic migration to update any existing data to the new format. So you shouldn't have to do anything if you are using date properties normally.

Comment: @Abhay - a fix for this has just been released on npm in version `0.13.0-rc`. This will automatically convert dates in the old format to the new format which should show then show up properly in the browser. Give it a try and let us know if you have any issues.